# PHP “warning include_once(): Failed to open stream” Simple HTML DOM in Wordpress Child Theme

Tags: php, functions, child-theme

I am trying to include [SIMPLE_HTML_DOM](https://github.com/voku/simple_html_dom) Library for my WordPress site. Unfortunately I get an warning.
Below is my file tree in child theme

[image]

```
include_once(): Failed opening '/var/www/html/wp-content/theme-child/simple_html_dom-master/voku/HtmlDomParser.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/wp-content/theme-child/functions.php on line 2
```

Below is what I have tried but without success

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/simple_html_dom-master/voku/simple_html_dom.php' );
include_once ('../../simple_html_dom-master/voku/helper/simple_html_dom.php');
require_once('../../simple_html_dom-master/voku/helper/simple_html_dom.php');
```

Any direction of how I can use it in wordpress site?

Comment: It depends on where you've put simple_html_dom-master.php. Where did you put it? And why is `theme-child` inside wp-content and not the themes directory?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I have updated my question